# Call method only if pointer is not nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an interface class and a pointer that may be `nullptr` and if it is I just skip the method call:

```
if (ptr != nullptr)
{
    ptr->SomeMethod();
}

...

if (ptr != nullptr)
{
    ptr->SomeOtherMethod();
}

...

if (ptr != nullptr)
{
    ptr->SomeMethodThatWasntMentionedBefore();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The below isn't quite correct:

> I can improve this code readability with the following macro:
>
> ```
> #define CALL_IF_NOT_NULLPTR(ptr, method_call) if (ptr != nullptr) { ptr->method_call; };
>
> CALL_IF_NOT_NULLPTR(ptr, SomeMethod());
> CALL_IF_NOT_NULLPTR(ptr, SomeOtherMethod());
> CALL_IF_NOT_NULLPTR(ptr, SomeMethodThatWasntMentionedBefore());
> ```
>
> Is there any way to do the same without macros (`C++11` solutions are
>   preferred)?

Is there any better way?

Comment: I don't see how your macro improves readability. But yo ucan simplity the ifs to `if (ptr)`.

Comment: @juanchopanza `if(ptr)` doesn't make it really better because of the implicit conversions to `bool` that I prefer to avoid it where it is possible.

Comment: Your question is based on the false premise that your macro improves code readability. It most certainly does not. Your macro makes the code harder to read and understand and won't work if `ptr` is anything non-trivial because it evaluates it twice. If `ptr` is trivial, there's no need for the macro. So what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Alex Why do you want to avoid the implicit conversions to `bool`?

Comment: You know, If I was ever tempted to abuse a macro like this, I'd probably define it as `OPTIONAL_DEREF(ptr) if(ptr) ptr` and then use as `OPTIONAL_DEREF(ptr)->SomeMethod()`. That way it will at least apply to more than just function calls.

Comment: @Holt simply because it doesn't warn you if you try to convert e.g. `float` to `bool` that is quite pointless.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I corrected the question.

Comment: You could interpret the fact that you do this so often that you want to make it more convenient as a sign that perhaps the rest of the code needs restructuring.

Answer (score 21):

Don't fight the language:

`if (ptr) ptr->SomeMethod();`

is extremely clear, readable, and has fewer characters than the difficult to debug macro alternative, or fancy wrapper classes. It is also explicit about the fact that `ptr` *might* be evaluated twice.

C++ doesn't (yet) have a "call only if not null operator" cf. C#

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes. Sometimes the answer *is* "there is no better way, so don't fight the language".

Comment: ^That, and this is about the least you can type to make your intentions clear

Answer (score 9):

Avoid macros, you can do this:

```
//Lambda call
template<typename T, typename F, typename... Args>
void call_if_not_nullptr(T* ptr, F&& function, Args&&... args)
{
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        std::forward<F>(function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//Member function call
template<typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
void call_if_not_nullptr(T* ptr, R(T::*mem_fun)(Args...), Args&&... args)
{
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        (ptr.*memfun)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

usage:

```
class SomeType
{
public:
    void noArgsFunction();
    void argsFunction(int, int);
}

SomeType* pointer = new SomeType();

//Member function call
call_if_not_nullptr(pointer, &SomeType::noArgsFunction);

//Member function call with arguments
call_if_not_nullptr(pointer, &SomeType::argsFunction, 0, 3);

//Lambda call
call_if_not_nullptr(pointer, [pointer](){ pointer->noArgsFunction(); });

//Lambda call with arguments
call_if_not_nullptr(pointer, [pointer](int a, int b){ pointer->argsFunction(); }, 0, 5);
```

I woudn't recommend it however, checking for a nullptr is clear enough and will give you clearer errors.

Comment: Yes, you could do this. But frankly typing it out doesn't flow of the keyboard so easily. The pointer to member syntax being required makes this of little usability. Still, good show of C++'s capabilities.

Comment: What about non-member functions with arguments. Couldn't your first template be modified to handle them similarly to your method version?

Comment: The lambda could be any function, it doesn't have to call a member.

Comment: I'm talking about *non*-member functions with arguments. It doesn't have an `Args` template argument.

Comment: Plus one, solely for evil genius, and you are careful to disclaim its use.

Comment: Added args for lambda call, you could however also just capture arguments instead of adding another argument, althought I geuss this has better forwarding.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to use overloading or specialisation with ``std::nullptr_t`` to get rid of the null check (like, if I'm remembering right, GSL's ``not_null`` is checking for ``nullptr``).

Comment: You could implement your own templated not_null type that can only construct from a pointer that is not a nullptr.

Comment: I was thinking of a specialisation (or overload) for ``nullptr_t`` that is a no-op. Giving a nullptr would use this specialisation/overload instead of having a runtime check (I'm not sure that it's possible).

Comment: Pointers are a dynamic language feature and the contents of a pointer cannot be checked at compile-time, just like the value of a mutable fundamental type is unknown at compile-time. There might be some constexpr magic though that I am unaware of. I'm geussing the GSL not_null pattern is also a runtime beast. I would say however that if you have to check for a nullptr there is something wrong with your ownership and ended up in a case that you don't know whether something is there anymore or not. This is a case that can be handled by weak_ptr.lock()

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always write a wrapper class checking for nullptr for you:

```
class
t_Wrapper
{
    private: t_Target * m_ptr;

    ...

    public: void
    SomeMethod()
    {
        if(m_ptr)
        {
            m_ptr->SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public: void
    SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        if(m_ptr)
        {
            m_ptr->SomeOtherMethod();
        }
    }

    ...

    public: void
    SomeMethodThatWasntMentionedBefore()
    {
        if(m_ptr)
        {
            m_ptr->SomeMethodThatWasntMentionedBefore();
        }
    }
};

t_Wrapper wrap(ptr);
wrap.SomeMethod();
wrap.SomeOtherMethod();
...
wrap.SomeMethodThatWasntMentionedBefore();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very maintainable. Every different function that is needed will have to be added and every class will need its own wrapper.

Comment: In this case all APIs are duplicated that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Personally I'm one the `if(ptr)` side, but you might be able to come up with a templated wrapper solution that calls the managed class's methods but I'm not sure of the syntax and I can't test it out right now.

Comment: @patatahooligan  @Alex The point of the wrapper is to eliminate nullptr check duplication in code. If you have like 50 calls to `foo` such wrapper will eliminated 50 nullptr checks and will add only 1 new inside of API duplication function. Such a tradeoff seems to be quite beneficial. And yet another benefit from wrapper may arise if it can be written in manner simplifying original API instead of just duplicating it.

Comment: The downvote is rough. This does answer the question "Is there any way to do the same without macros". Whether it's maintainable is a different issue.